# How to only deploy changed project files in Windows Azure?

Tags: asp.net, salesforce

I am working on a web project in ASP.NET which is integrated with Salesforce. I have published my web project in Windows Azure. Now I have some changes in particular files and I want to deploy these changes only rather than complete project.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Web Deploy from within Visual studio, it will automatically only deploy the changed files in a differential manner. Alternatively, if you are using Azure VM's or a Cloud Service (which is actually VM's), you can connect to the machine(s) using RDP and update select files manually. You can get the RDP information to the machine from the Azure Portal.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-log-on-windows-server/